# MSSQL Stored procedure conversion to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Site is already built in .Net where it is using SQL server stored procedure. Now we are converting into PHP for that we are also altering stored procedure in MySQL.

In one of stored procedure there is some code to multiple insert and update which is achieved in SQL stored procedure as follows:

```
MERGE
    INTO products T
    USING SELECT STATEMENT
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE STATEMENT
WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT STATEMENT
```

I need an alternative to this approach in MySQL stored procedure syntax. Please guide me through how can I achieve this.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace this with `on duplicate key update`.

For this, you will need a unique key on the columns that specify "matched".

Note:  This will (definitely) not replace all `merge` code.  However, your example seems like it is implementing exactly this logic.  Otherwise, you can use `if` with `update` and `insert` statements to pretty much do the same thing.

Comment: By this how can I achieve combination of two columns except the key column to decide whether to update record or not.